# Pandas: how to groupy per different days and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like the following (here a subset):

```
df1
    ID                                                     zone     date
0   6a93b747472484e41f969a0ac02b96161eb0af9edb1fe4...   01529224    2020-01-01
1   6a93b747472484e41f969a0ac02b96161eb0af9edb1fe4...   01529224    2020-01-01
2   6a93b747472484e41f969a0ac02b96161eb0af9edb1fe4...   01529224    2020-01-01
3   6a93b747472484e41f969a0ac02b96161eb0af9edb1fe4...   01529224    2020-01-01
4   6a93b747472484e41f969a0ac02b96161eb0af9edb1fe4...   01529224    2020-01-01
```

If I count the distinct ID per day I have

```
tmp = df1.groupby(['date']).agg({"ID": pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()
tmp.head()

     date        ID
0   2019-12-31  4653
1   2020-01-01  6656
2   2020-01-02     1
```

Now if I group by zone and date I have the following:

```
distinctID = df1.groupby(['date', "zone"]).agg({"ID": pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()

       date         zone    ID
0   2019-12-31  00023901    1
1   2019-12-31  00025441    2
2   2019-12-31  00025442    2
3   2019-12-31  00025443    3
4   2019-12-31  00025444    2
```

If I count the ID for each day, how I have:

```
tmp1 = distinctID.groupby(['date']).agg({"ID": 'sum'}).reset_index()
tmp1.head()

       date      ID
0   2019-12-31  5833
1   2020-01-01  11837
2   2020-01-02  1
```

Why I do not get the same counting per each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your code is not same, I try change data for see it:

```
print (df1)
         date   zone ID
0  2019-12-31  23901  a
0  2019-12-31  23901  b
0  2019-12-31  25441  b
1  2019-12-31  25441  a
2  2019-12-31  25442  a

#only 2 unique values per date
tmp = df1.groupby(['date']).agg({"ID": pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()
print (tmp)
         date  ID
0  2019-12-31   2 <-a, b

#if test per 2 columns there are more unique values, because tested separately
distinctID = df1.groupby(['date', "zone"]).agg({"ID": pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()
print (distinctID)
         date   zone  ID
0  2019-12-31  23901   2 <-a, b
1  2019-12-31  25441   2 <-a, b
2  2019-12-31  25442   1 <-a

#sum is different, because unique values are counts per 2 columns
tmp1 = distinctID.groupby(['date']).agg({"ID": 'sum'}).reset_index()
print (tmp1)
         date  ID
0  2019-12-31   5 <-a, b, a, b, a
```

Comment: Well, why you count five `ID` in the last groupby? How can you return the number of distinct IDs?